# JavaScript FileReader to read txt or image files and place contents on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, filereader

Below is part of a web drawing app using HTML5 Canvas.

My next step is to allow contents from local files to be selected and rendered onto the canvas. The files can be `txt` or common image formats like `png`.

In the code, the file is selected then if the extension is `txt` the contents are treated as text, and if the extension is `png` the image data should be read and rendered on the canvas.

However, with the png file, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D':
 The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or 
HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or
 SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.
```

Here is the code:

```
<script>

function addTxtFileContent(e) {
   console.log('addTxtFileContent');
   var fc =  e.target.result;

   console.log('addFileContent: ' + fc);
   var fsize = document.getElementById("TextFontSize").value;
   var font = "";
   if ( textitalic ) font += 'italic ';
   if ( textbold ) font += 'bold ';
   font +=   fsize  + 'px ' +
             document.getElementById("TextFontList").value;
   console.log('addFileContent font: ' + font );
   context.font = font;
   context.fillStyle = scolor;
   context.textAlign = textalign;
   context.fillText(fc, 400, 200);

}

function addImgFileContent(e, img) {
   console.log('addImgFileContent');
   context.drawImage(img, 100, 100);

}


function readFile(e) {
  console.log('readFile');
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) return;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var ext = String(file.name).split('.').pop();
  console.log('readFile name: ' + file.name + ' ext:' + ext);

  switch ( ext )
  {
     case 'txt':
        reader.onload = function(e) {
           addTxtFileContent(e);
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
        break;

     case 'png':
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         reader.onload = function (e) {
            var image=new Image();
            image.src=e.target.result;
            image.onload = function () {
               addImgFileContent(image);  // <<< Error reported here
            };
         }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Incorrect placement of parameters `addImgFileContent(image);` should be `addImgFileContent(e, image);`

Comment: you pass a single argument to `addImgFileContent ()`. The second argument is `undefined` and not of the specified type.

Comment: Oh dear.  Been looking at that for hours and didn't spot it. Thanks guys. It's working now.